# What are the recent research directions in the topic of circuit lower bounds from derandomization?

Tags: reference-request, circuits, randomness, pseudo-random-generators

I am thinking of the classical paper, https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~kabanets/Research/poly.html

Can someome link to some papers/reviews that give a sampling of what are the recent thoughts in this direction?

---

I am equally happy to know of what are the recent directions in the topic of pseudorandomness and derandomization.

Comment: You will get more responses and exposure on cstheory.se.

Comment: If you'd like to see this migrated to CSTheory.SE, please flag it for moderator attention using "flag" under the question (but don't cross-post).  Also, I suggest that you edit the question to include a full reference to the paper (title, authors, where published) so that the question will still be meaningful in case the link dies, and so that the question can be findable by others using search in case others have similar questions.  Also, what research have you done?  Have you used Google Scholar to look through other papers that cite it?

Comment: Finally: please don't use the [tag:reference-question] tag (this might not be obvious, but that's more or less reserved for special purposes) -- I'll fix that for you.

Comment: @D.W. Ofcourse I have seen a lot of papers on this topic! But I don't have a big-picture of this pursuit. What was I was hoping is if some expert can give a short high-level view of what are the big themes and directions of work currently being pursued in this particular field.

Comment: more on recent developments [here](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/2015/05/01/algebraic-circuit-complexity-valiants-vpvnp-recent-advances-breakthroughs/) tying it into arithmetic complexity etc

Comment: 1. My point was that if you look through papers on Google Scholar you should be able to figure out for yourself if a survey paper already exists -- if a survey paper exists, it probably cites that paper.  2. If you've read lots of papers on the topic, then please edit the question to summarize the main themes/ideas you already know of.  Sharing what you already know helps everyone, and makes it more likely you'll get a good answer.  I encourage you to read http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, esp. "Questions should be based on knowledge sharing, not on shirking".

Comment: @vzn Thanks for the link! Your list is interesting! Can you share some thoughts about how/if you see these developments in arithmetic complexity being related to the progress in the direction of pseudorandomness and extractors as in the recent works of Raghu Meka, Xin Li etc ?

Comment: hi, yw, was thinking of writing up a survey on extractors also, have many links on them, but not familiar with intricate details. maybe drop by [chat] for more discussion, not sure what work in particular you are citing.